# WinApi: функция MapWindowPoints принцип работы?

Tags: c++, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста принцип работы функции MapWindowPoints. Конечно же я прочитал на MSDN`е описание и попробывал, но что то не понимаю, как она работает в итоге:

```
HWND Parent_HWND = FindWindowA(NULL, "Калькулятор");

   POINT my_point;

   my_point.x = 10;
   my_point.y = 0;

   int my_int = MapWindowPoints(Parent_HWND, HWND_DESKTOP, &my_point, 0);

   cout << endl;
   cout << LOWORD(my_int) << endl;
   cout << HIWORD(my_int) << endl;
```

В описании функции сказано, что она возвращает int:

> Если функция завершается успешно, младшее слово возвращаемого значения представляет собой количество пикселей, добавленных к горизонтальной координате каждой исходной точки для вычисления горизонтальной координаты каждой целевой точки.

Мне всегда возвращается координата X и Y - точно соотвесвующии левому верхнему углу окна калькулятора, вне зависимости от того, какие значения я указываю в  my_point.x и  my_point.y.

Я не понимаю, что в итоге делает или должна делать эта функция ? :(

Comment: результат сохранен в `my_point`

Comment: А последний параметр разве не `1` должен быть?

Comment: HolyBlackCat, да да - 1. Это я просто тут случайно 0 указал.

Comment: Maxim Timakov, Спасибо! Я почему то зациклился на возвращаемом значении и все и забыл прочитать про POINT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MapWindowPoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mapwindowpoints) преобразует клиентские координаты окна `hWndFrom` в клиентские координаты `hWndTo`, т.е. для заданной координаты передвигает начало координат в другую точку.

[image: демонстрация]

На картинке 3 координаты:

- зеленая и синяя - начала координат окон (клиентской области)
- красная - исходная координата, которую нам нужно преобразовать

Пара (x1, y1) определяет координату относительно синего начала координат
Пара (x2, y2) определяет координату относительно зеленого начала координат

Допустим, hWndFrom - дескриптор окна с синим началом координат клиентской области, а hWndTo - дескриптор окна с зеленым началом координат клиентской области, тогда если в MapWindowPoints передать пару (x1, y1), то на выходе получим (x2, y2)

p.s.: x2, конечно, в данном случае отрицательная